# Google Webmaster Tools + AngularJS issue

Tags: angularjs, nginx, web-crawler, google-search-console

I made a one page website with the framework AngularJS. I configured my server (nginx) to redirect crawlers to a static HTML page. I use https://prerender.io, my JS adds a ! after the # in my URL, I also added the meta `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`. So my website URL looks like thise: example.com/#!/. I registered both domain names (with and without www) in the Google Tools. I cached those URLs into prerender.io. The robots.txt is registered and looks like this: User-agent: *
Allow: /. I also registered my sitemap.xml: 

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/#!/</loc>
        <lastmod>2014-12-08</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
    </urlset>`

On the prerender website I can see Crawl Stats, the Google Bot has visited my website. But on the Google Webmasters Tools my Structured Data don't appear. When I fetch as Google it does not load the static HTML page, it only does it when I add ?_escaped_fragment_=.

Did I miss something?

Comment: @JohnMueller [my website](http://atelierdusaintex.co.kr/).

Comment: The pre-rendered version at /?_escaped_fragment_=/ is pretty empty ... Also when rendering the JS version of your site, it takes a really long time before the content appears (6+ seconds), so we can't see it either way.